# Array Formula on Range of Sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula on several sheets in cell F1

```
{=SUM(IF(MONTH(A3:A210)=1,B3:B210,0))}
```

I have this formula on a totals sheet

```
=SUM(Start:End!F1)
```

I've been trying to combine the two into one formula on the totals page. Thank you everyone getting me this far.

Comment: I'd advise you to leave this just as it is. It's possible to use a single formula, but that's complex and inefficient and probably best avoided

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a pivot table using the wizard which allows you to choose multiple consolidation ranges.

I was given the idea here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-PivotTable-3ae257d2-ca94-49ff-a481-e9fc8adeeeb5